# Test framework for Unix application testing

Tags: test-automation-framework, desktop-application, linux

I'm looking for recommendations on test automation framework for running a suite of command line applications.

I'm used to more development unit testing type of frameworks such as *xUnit* or *MSTest* based tools.

I'm looking for something targeted more towards a compiled executable types, rather than require access to the programs and classes.

I would like something that has a common setup/tear-down mechanism (depending on the application, we may need need to construct a queue with the queue manager) and will have common reporting feature to other tools such as Jenkins.

We've used ***cTest*** but I find that a bit lacking for the setup.  I've started looking at ***shUnit2*** but I'm curious what else may be available.

The target is Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

Check  [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org). It does what you need and can be harnessed to do a lot more too. After initial setting up it is easy to manage. It has nice reports, integrates nicely to Jenkins and also to Test management tools if you need broader view on how testing is connected to user stories / requirements etc.

Answer (score 1):

I’m building something similar using Python and Proboscis (nose with TestNG features like inter test dependencies).

Proboscis allows setup and tear down functions globally and per class